# Getting started with the Form API and Ajax framework

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm really struggling to understand how to use Drupal 7's Form API in conjunction with its Ajax framework. I'd like to accomplish the following:

On certain pages, multiple nodes may appear. Each one of these nodes should have a comment form appear right below it. When the user submits a comment, it should be done via Ajax and the resulting comment should then appear under the node in question.

Can someone give me an overview of the steps that are required to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is [a module for submitting forms with Ajax](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_comments).

> Provides AJAX comments to Drupal sites. Features:
>
> - Makes AJAX submits
> - Allows replies to comments on the actual thread page
> - AJAX comments deleting
> - Works with CAPTCHA
> - Cool jQuery sliding

Comment: They only have a dev version for D7.

Comment: Indeed, but if you download the module and take a look a the code, you can get started on how to implement Ajax into your forms.

Comment: Though it is in dev the ajax_comments module currently does what you are asking for. If you have any issues please file a ticket in the module's issue queue.

Comment: @maxedison Have a look at the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/ajax_comments?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All), it doesn't look like there's anything particularly prohibitive in there, I'd just get stuck in and give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Examples](http://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.  There is loads of information and examples on how to implement AJAX with Drupal 7 forms :-)